# rust-gpu complains about mismatching toolchain file

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, rust-cargo

rust-gpu says:

> Copy the rust-toolchain file to your project. (You must use the same version of Rust as rust-gpu.)

So I copied that file into my root getting `rust-toolchain` with contents:

```ini
# If you see this, run `rustup self update` to get rustup 1.23 or newer.

# NOTE: above comment is for older `rustup` (before TOML support was added),
# which will treat the first line as the toolchain name, and therefore show it
# to the user in the error, instead of "error: invalid channel name '[toolchain]'".

[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2022-10-29"
components = ["rust-src", "rustc-dev", "llvm-tools-preview"]
# commit_hash = 9565dfeb4e6225177bbe78f18cd48a7982f34401

# Whenever changing the nightly channel, update the commit hash above, and make
# sure to change REQUIRED_TOOLCHAIN in crates/rustc_codegen_spirv/src/build.rs also.
```

Then I tried building by doing cargo-run, getting:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `rustc_codegen_spirv v0.4.0-alpha.17 (https://github.com/EmbarkStudios/rust-gpu#fabcbd9c)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/makogan/rust_never_engine/target/debug/build/rustc_codegen_spirv-b4185236522e0515/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=RUSTGPU_SKIP_TOOLCHAIN_CHECK

  --- stderr
  error: wrong toolchain detected (found commit hash `e631891f7ad40eac3ef58ec3c2b57ecd81e40615`, expected `9565dfeb4e6225177bbe78f18cd48a7982f34401`).
  Make sure your `rust_toolchain` file contains the following:
  -------------
  [toolchain]
  channel = "nightly-2022-10-29"
  components = ["rust-src", "rustc-dev", "llvm-tools-preview"]
```

I am confused, the toolchain file says the same thing as the error message, what did I do wrong?

Comment: The commit hash in your error message belongs to `nightly-2022-11-14` double check that your `rust-toolchain` file contains the correct version `2022-10-29` and maybe try to reinstall the nightly-toolchains in question. Also just to make sure you're running `rustup` to manage your toolchains right? Else the toolchain file will have no effect.

Comment: @cafce25 How do I tell rustup to use the rust-toolchain file to setup the project?

Comment: [`rustup` will use the `rustup-toolchain` file in the root of your project.](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) You could also try `rustup run nigtly-2022-10-29 cargo run` to make sure you're running rustups `cargo` with the right nightly version.

Comment: @cafce25 manually selecting the toolchain  like that works, no idea why it doesn;t with just the rust-toolchain file on the root directory.

Comment: You probably have another (not managed by rustup) toolchain installed wich gets picked over the one from `rustup` I'd guess. On unix like OSs you can run `which cargo` to find out where the cargo you're running is located, maybe that helps solve this mystery.

Comment: @cafce25 /home/makogan/.cargo/bin/cargo Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250504/discussion-between-cafce25-and-makogan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running a different version of nightly than the crate requires.
To check the version of cargo try to run `cargo --version` from within the project directory. If it shows anything else than the version you specified in the `rust-toolchain` file then you can try and check out the list below for possible fixes.

Make sure that:

1. The `cargo` you're using is managed by `rustup` if it is `cargo +stable --version` should show a version number and not an error.
2. The `rust-toolchain` is in the same directory as `Cargo.toml` if it's not copy or move it there.
3. There is no override on the crates directory. You can list them with `rustup override list` if the crate where the error appears is listed you can unset it with `rustup override unset` from within the crate root.

In this specific case `3.` was the culprit.